# How to initialize a new screen and go to it, while adding it to a table view in the background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to go straight to a screen that is normally reached through tapping on a table view cell - Basically the user enters a page name on `Screen A`, and then is taken the table view, `Screen B`, where the name they entered is now the first and only cell in the table view. Then they tap on that cell to reach `Screen C`.

Now I want to cut `Screen B` out of the equation - I'll be embedding that table in a slide-out menu so I don't want it presented at all, I just want to update the table in the background.

This is my code so far, all on the setup page (`Screen A`):

This is the `prepareForSegue`, that's called when the user finishes signing up for the app and presses "done":

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "initChat") {
        let chatVc = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
        let roomVc = RoomsTableViewController()
                if let roomName = self.chatRoomNameTextField.text {

                    let newRoomRef = roomRef.childByAutoId()
                    let roomItem = [
                        "name": roomName
                    ]
                    newRoomRef.setValue(roomItem)

                    // Start participants list with current user
                    let participantsRef = newRoomRef.child("participants")
                    let newParticipantRef = participantsRef.childByAutoId()

                    if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
                        newParticipantRef.setValue(uid)
                    }
                }
                roomVc.senderDisplayName = "Joe"
    }
}
```

And this is an observer for Firebase that is in charge of updating the table view once the user enters a name:

```
    private func observeRooms() {
        // Observe method to listen for new channels being written to Firebase
        let roomVc = RoomsTableViewController()

        roomVc.roomRefHandle = roomVc.roomRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            let roomData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let id = snapshot.key

            if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
                if let name = roomData["name"] as! String!, name.characters.count > 0 {
                    roomVc.rooms.append(Room(id: id, name: name, participants: [uid]))
                    roomVc.tableView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print("Error! Could not decode channel data")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

And this is the IBAction for the "done" button being pressed:

```
@IBAction func setupDoneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    setUserInfo()
    observeRooms()

    let room = rooms  // <-- This is where I need to indicate that I want to go to the first room in the table
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "initChat", sender: room)
}
```

In this case I know that the screen I want to load will always be the very first cell in the table view, because at this point it will be the first cell created. But I don't know how to specify that without the index path in the table view's methods.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For update the table view use:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

What you have to do is: After the user enters the search value, and press the button, *setupDoneButtonPressed()* will be executed, after that, you have to set new data into a global variable. When data was set, you have to reload de tableview. I think this could help, let me know if you tried this.

Comment: I do reload the table view in the `observeRooms` function with `roomVc.tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: Does it work?, I reviewed your code and I´m not sure it "rooms" variable has data.

Comment: It doesn't, it's definitely looking like rooms is not getting the data although I don't know what else I can do - I have all the code that would normally be run in the RoomsTableViewController, in the setup controller instead (minus the actual tableview methods of course) so I can bypass the rooms controller. This is the rooms controller: https://pastebin.com/9EkCw23C and the setup controller: https://pastebin.com/YY4MxjgX .